# How make text moving from left to right in Android?

Tags: android, textview

I use this code to make text move and it moves correctly from right to left.

Nevertheless, I want to make the text in **TextView** move from left to right.

Here is my current code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mylinenews"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"

    android:text="textmoving textmoving textmoving textmoving textmoving textmoving textmoving textmoving textmoving textmoving "
    android:textColor="#fff"
/>
```

How can I modify this code so the text moves from left to right?

Comment: U want to shake the text or just want to move ??

Answer (score 4):

Use below xml code in anim folder under res :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-3%p"
        android:toXDelta="3%p"
        android:duration="1200" />
</set>
```

And, just add this to your textview :

```
yourTextView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.move));
```

Comment: you can handle movement position under xml attributes `fromXDelta` and `toXDelta`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to shake the text than In Your Activity Use

```
Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(YourActivity.this, R.anim.shake);
            YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.startAnimation(shake);
```

Create a **folder name anim** in res i.e. res..> anim and create two xml in anim folder 
1) `shake.xml`
2) `cycle.xml`

In Your shake.xml  write

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="20" android:duration="7000"
    android:interpolator="@anim/cycle" />
```

and in your cycle.xml write

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:cycles="10" />
```

Enjoy Animated Text in android text view :)

Comment: this is shake for text but i just need to make text move from left to right instead in right to left

Comment: Yes I wrote If you want to shake the text friom left to write than the above 1 is answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Left to right animation:

```
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1500.0f); // new TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta,float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)

    animation.setDuration(1500); // animation duration
    animation.setRepeatCount(1); // animation repeat count
    animation.setFillAfter(false);
    your_view .startAnimation(animation);//your_view for mine is imageView
```

Repeated animation (for eg. left to right and right to left):

```
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1500.0f); // new TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta,float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
    animation.setDuration(1500); // animation duration
    animation.setRepeatCount(4); // animation repeat count
    animation.setRepeatMode(2); // repeat animation (left to right, right to left)

    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    your_view .startAnimation(animation);//your_view for mine is imageView
```

Comment: this is moving Up and Down

Answer (score 0):

I know i am a too late to answer but the simplest way is to add to your textview in the xml file

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     animation.setDuration(1500); // animation duration
                           animation.setRepeatCount(4); // animation repeat count
                           animation.setRepeatMode(2); // repeat animation (left to right, right to left)
 animation.setFillAfter(true);
                        textview.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

The working code for the moving textview left to right is

```
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textscroll);
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 1500.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // new TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta,float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)

animation.setDuration(7500); // animation duration, change accordingly
animation.setRepeatCount(1); // animation repeat count
animation.setFillAfter(false);
tv2 .startAnimation(animation);//your_view for which you need animation
```